# Enumerate all windows created by an application

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a WinForms application. That application have a rich functionality. It can create many windows (System.Windows.Forms.Form). Application is not MDI. I need to enumerate (I need to know) all windows created by that application. It creates windows in the same thread. I mean it doesn't create new process or something.

Of course, I can store a link to a new window created inside an application but it's a difficult solution and doesn't fit me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [`OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx)?